# How can I return values of each object wihtin List of Object using API

Tags: c#, api

I have created an object called UserModel. I have also created a method that returns a List of User Models within a database. Below is my method for returning Users from database.

```
static public List<UserModel> SearchUsers(string tableName)
    {

        string commandString = $"SELECT* FROM [{tableName}]";

        using SqlConnection connection = new(ConnectionSQL.connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        using SqlCommand command = new(commandString, connection);
        //Console.WriteLine(command);
        using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        var users = new List<UserModel>();


        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                users.Add(new UserModel
                {
                    ID = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                    LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                    Email = reader.GetString(3),
                    Phone = reader.GetString(4),
                    Password = reader.GetString(5),
                  
                });

            }
        }
     return users;
    }
```

Now this is the code I am using for my API. I am confused on how I would be able to get an api to read the objects within the list.

```
 [ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Users : ControllerBase
{
  

    [HttpGet(Name = "UsersSearch")]
    public ActionResult<List<UserModel>> Get()
    {

        List<UserModel> myValues = DL.DLUser.SearchUsers("Users");

        return myValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can iterate over a list `myValues`, using `foreach()`, `for()`

Comment: do you want to search your users via ID or Name?